# Unable to start debugging. failed to process configuration file - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, assembly, masm, masm32

I'm trying to debug a small assembly program using Visual studio community 2017 and masm32 on windows 10(64-bit). But I'm keep getting this error:

[image]

In my project, I defined a windows 10 subsystem. After that, I connected visual studio to masm32 using "right click on my project"=> "Build Dependencies" => "Build Customizations" => "masm"

Here is my very small program:

```
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data
.code
main proc
    ret
main endp

end main
```

But I'm unable to start debugging.

Here is what I've tried until now:

1.restart visual studio several times, Delete all the existing projects and recreate them.

2.Use other directories for my projects.

3.reinstall masm32.

But nothing seems to work. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: There's a "Reset all Settings" under `Tools/Import and Export Settings`.  Have you tried that?  Warning: This resets ALL VS settings back to their defaults (directories, window positions, exception settings, etc).  You might want to make sure you save the existing settings in case this doesn't solve your problems.  At least you'd be no worse off.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your error as **text** as well as including a screen shot?  On stackoverflow we ask that you include your code, error messages, exception details and other textual data as text, not as an image.  For why, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3744182) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/3744182).

Comment: I'm not sure of VS2017, but VS2015 and earlier versions include ML.EXE, whch is  a 32 bit version of MASM, and ML64.EXE/, which is a 64 bit version of MASM. These should output compatible object files. You may need a custom build step to invoke ML or ML64.

Comment: Works here. It is an issue of VS, not MASM32. Try to [repair VS with the Visual Studio Installer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37492.modify-repair-and-uninstall-visual-studio-2017-using-visual-studio-installer.aspx).  What do you mean with "windows 10 subsystem"?

Answer (score 0):

The only time I had this error (which was in Visual Studio 2019) I eventually figured out that disabling Resharper & then restarting VS fixed it.